# Mean value of sqrt. root cox-ingersoll-ross process

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Consider the so-called Cox-Ingersoll-Process model

\begin{equation}
   dr_t=a(b-r_t)dt+\sigma \sqrt{r_t}dW_t
\end{equation}

It can be shown (Wikipedia), that the mean of this process is

\begin{equation}
   \langle r_t \rangle = r_0 e^{-at }+ b(1-e^{-at})^2
\end{equation}
for some initial value $r_0$.

Consider now the transformation $Y_t=\sqrt{r_t}$. By Itô calculus, it can be shown that this new process fulfills the following stochastic differential equation

\begin{equation}
   dY_t=\left(\frac{\alpha}{Y_t}-\beta Y_t\right)dt + \gamma dW_t
\end{equation}

This transformation is called the Lamperti transformation and is a common way to shift the nonlinearity from the diffusion coefficient into the drift.

For certain reasons, I need to estimate $\langle Y_t \rangle$. Can it be solved?

As a naïve approach, one can assume that $\langle Y_t \rangle=\sqrt{\langle r_t \rangle}$. However, after some numerical simulations, I realized this was wrong.

Comment: Since $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is concave, you have by Jensen's inequality $E[\sqrt{r_t}]\leq \sqrt{E[r_t]}$. The distribution of the CIR process at fixed time $r_t$ is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model#Distribution) so you might have luck with the integral.

Comment: Numerically, I checked that this inequality is correct. Do I understand correctly that the only way to proceed would be to compute $E[\sqrt{r}]=\int \sqrt{r} P(r) dr$? being $P(r)$ is the probability distribution.

Comment: that is indeed what I mean when I refer to the integral. It is a way, not the only way for sure.

Comment: I just checked numerically with Mathematica and it is correct, it gives me the correct mean. I just hope now I can get some analytics. Thanks!